# Scraping data from multiple places on same HTML with Beautiful Soup (Python)

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have problems with scraping data from certain URL with Beautiful Soup.
I've successfully made part where my code opens text file with list of URL's and goes through them.
First problem that I encounter is when I want to go through two separate places on HTML page. 
With code that I wrote so far, it only goes through first "class" and just doesn't want to search and scrap another one that I defined.

Second issue is that I can get data only if I run my script in terminal with:

```
python mitel.py > mitel.txt
```

Output that I get is not the one that I want. I am just looking for two strings from it, but I cannot find a way to extract it.

Finally, there's no way I can get my results to write to CSV. 
I only get last string of last URL from url-list into my CSV.

Can you assist TOTAL beginner in Python?

Here's my script:

```
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv  
import os
import itertools


import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')



with open('urllist.txt') as inf:
urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
for url in urls:
    site = urllib2.urlopen(url)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site.read(), 'html.parser')
for target in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["tel-number", "tel-result     main"]}):
    finalt = target.text.strip()
    print finalt

with open('output_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(finalt)
```

For some reason, I cannot paste succesfully targeted HTML code, so I'll just put a link here to one of the pages, and if it gets needed, I'll try to somehow paste it, although, its very big and complex.

[Targeted URL for scraping](https://tel.search.ch/?was=dado&pages=200)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you assign only last value in `finalt = target.text.strip()`. You have to use list to keep all values `finalt = []` and later `finalt.append( target.text.strip() )`

Comment: to get two separated places on HTML page you have to use two separated `findall()` .

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to get some results with the help of @furas and google. 
With this code, I can get all "a" from the page, and then in MS Excel I was able to get rid of everything that wasn't name and phone.
Sorting and rest of the stuff is also done in excel... I guess I am to big of a newbie to accomplish everything in one script.

```
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv  
import os
import itertools
import requests



import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


finalt = []
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://163.158.216.152:80'})
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
with open('mater.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        site = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site.read(), 'html.parser')
    for target in soup.findAll('a'):
        finalt.append( target.text.strip() )
        print finalt




with open('imena1-50.csv', 'wb') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     for i in finalt:
         writer.writerow([i])
```

It also uses proxy.. sort off. Didn't get it to get proxies from .txt list.

Not bad for first python scraping, but far from efficient and the way I imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your selector is wrong, try this

```
for target in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["tel-number",'tel-result-main']}):
```